# How can I move a mailbox from Apple Mail to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, apple-mail, osx-yosemite

I am using OS X Yosemite and Apple Mail. I am a realtor and I create a new mailbox in Mail.app for each transaction. When a deal is complete, I would like to move the mailbox to the cloud for permanent storage and get it off the mail server (I do not have my own mail server).

So basically, I want to be able to move an entire folder of email—as opposed to a single email—to a folder in Dropbox which also contains documents generated elsewhere.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Another option is to save all your selected email as RTF to your DropBox folder: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3831842

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you could do:

- Open Finder
- Press <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd>
- A window will open
- Enter `~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes`

You'll be taken to a folder with all your local mailboxes, which you can then just take and move over to your Dropbox. Before moving them, I would first quit Mail.app.

Once you've moved the mailbox to Dropbox, you can still look at the messages inside through Finder (as `.emix` files), and I guess it would be easy to just move it back to Mail.app in case you need it.

Note that this only works for mailboxes locally stored on your machine. You can't move folders that are inside an IMAP account, because those are just "virtual" folders on the mail server.

Comment: Note: I haven't tried this, as I don't use Apple Mail, but would be nice to hear back from you whether it works.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, despite the fact I use IMAP.  Upon opening the finder and typing CMD Shift G I got a box that contained ~/Library/Mail/V2/Mail Data.  When I tried to enter the code you suggested I got "File Not Found."     I would think I am not the first person to want to move a file folder of email to safe keeping outside of Apple mail and Apple Help would be able to address it.  They couldn't.  Thanks for trying.  sj

Comment: Like I said, you first have to have a local mailbox. Otherwise the mails will only be stored on the server. So when you create a local mailbox, and move the files from your IMAP account there, then `~/Library/Mail/V2/Mailboxes` will exist and you can move the mails on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation trying to move multiple Mac Mail emails to dropbox. So far I haven't been successful other than navigating through the root of where Mac Mail stores emails and then transferring them over in their numerical nomenclature. What I mean is instead of the email being titled by whatever the subject is, it will be something like 10051.emlx.

But in navigating all the way through that root path, I think when you save mails locally on your computer the way slhck is suggesting, it stores them in a new folder under the "Mail" heading labeled "V3" instead of V2 as he states. So if anyone else is having this issue, try making that one alteration and see if it works.

Now that all that is said, I did note that any file I moved in this method opened in a "raw" format, with all the script code showing, so it is very difficult to navigate through. Just FYI.